# Change background-image of element 5 times on scroll down

Tags: jquery

I'd like to have a scrolling down effect on a page, that when you reach one slide it stops on that slide but as you keep scrolling down the background-image of an element keeps changing. I'm looking at scrolldeck.js http://johnpolacek.github.io/scrolldeck.js/decks/responsive/

to do this but I'm not sure how I could remove/add class depending on the amount the use has scrolled. Any clues? Thanks!

Comment: Look into: http://prinzhorn.github.io/skrollr/ and http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/

Comment: possible duplicate of [execute code on scrolling down an element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18491489/execute-code-on-scrolling-down-an-element)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use window scroll to determine what image to display and when. quick example.

```
var currentUrl = null;
var imageControl = function( event ) {
   var fromTop = $(window).scrollTop(), // The distance from the top of the page
       url = null;

   if(fromTop < 2000) {
     url = 'http://placehold.it/1000/FF0';
   } else if (fromTop > 2000) {
     url = 'http://placehold.it/1000/F00';
   }

   if(url !== currentUrl) {
      $('body').css('background', 'url(' + url + ')');
      currentUrl = url;
   }
};

$(window).scroll(imageControl);
```

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/2Pfsy/**

You can improve this a lot so it doesn't run this code when it doesn't need to etc....

Comment: cool thanks, is there a way to stop on a slide when it reaches it? I understand you have to apply position fixed to it but can that be done with scroll deck?

Comment: I haven't/don't use scrolldeck.

Comment: I used this code to fix a issue i was having and it works great! But i'm getting a "flicker" when i scroll because its evaluating the value with each scroll. is there a fix for this?

Comment: Yeah, ill post a solution now.