# Change logo when scrolled to a certain div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, scroll

I have 4 divs named as `#jungle`, `#tour`, `#photography`, `#culture` in my page. I want to change my logo when I scrolled to certain div. 
That mean when I scrolled jungle div logo should change to `jungle.png` (I'm using logo as background image on `.navbar-brand`).On other divs logo should change accordingly.
I' using `boostrap` and logo is on left top of `navbar`.

I there way to do this without using fixed heights?

Comment: Yes please. we can do that! But we need some code to work on. What have you tried??

Comment: var t = $("#jungle").offset().top;

$(document).scroll(function(){
    if($(this).scrollTop() > t)
    {   
        $('.navbar-brand').css({"background":"url(images/jungle.png)"});
    }
});

Comment: paste your html + javascript + css code, it would be very helpful if you paste it in fiddle and provide us the link.

Comment: I used that code but image change before reach the div and doesn't change back after scrolled out of div.

Comment: You can either use some libraries like `jQuery.waypoints` or write simple `$(window).resize` handler. Read this article: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18495070/change-background-image-of-element-5-times-on-scroll-down

Comment: satish i suggest you to put the code from your comments to the question

Comment: Please put `html` and `js` too!! A fiddle would be great!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to use logo as background image and use some jquery to make this happen.

```
//change logo on activities panel

 $(document).scroll(function(){
   var h = $(".nav").height() * 1.5;
   var t1 = $("#water").offset().top;
    if(($(this).scrollTop() + h) >= t1)
    {   
       $('.navbar-brand').css({"background":"url(images/logo2.png)"});

     }
     else{}
 });

$(document).scroll(function(){
var h = $(".nav").height() * 1.5;
var t2 = $("#jungle").offset().top;
if($(this).scrollTop() + h >= t2)
{   
 $('.navbar-brand').css({"background":"url(images/logo3.png)"});

}
else{}
   });
```

and some css like this

```
.navbar-brand {
padding-top: 0;
background: url(../images/logo.png);
background-position: center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
width: 146px;
height: 67px;
transition: all .1s;}
```

and it worked!.